# Optimize ArcServer Service Drawing Speed

Tags: arcgis-server, web-mapping, web-service, geocortex

I am managing an ArcGIS service that is used by Geocortex Essentials as a web map app for some users. The feedback I have got so far is that it doesn't refresh fast enough. I'm looking for some answers to these questions:

1. Do labels with a mask on them draw slower?
2. What point symbol draws faster: Character or Simple?
3. Does having a label only draw in its polygon result in slower labelling?

Comment: Hey bud, I'm glad I got you finally on this site, it's great! You need to phrase your question a little more like a question and less general.

Comment: Have you seen Esri's presentation on [best practices for map services](http://video.esri.com/watch/642/best-practices-for-designing-effective-map-services)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Additional information such as how many and what type of layers the service contains, as well as how the service is used (as a basemap? for example) by GeoCortex will yield better answers.